# How to fix a null result from express route?

Tags: node.js, express, router

I'm getting one problem with one route on the express, when I try to search a data from one parameter with a URL, I'm getting a null response.

Router:

```js
router.get('/:ownerId', (req, res) => {
  const ownerId = req.params.ownerId;

  res.json({ ownerId: ownerId });
});
```

The entire url would be `http://localhost:3000/bots/:ownerId`.

**I've tried to make the request through req.query, and the same problem happens.**
The route is in the same file with two other routes (I think it doesn't mean anything).

All the bots **GET** on the file:

```js
// List all bots on database | WORKING
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const Model = await Bot.find();

  if(Model.length === 0) {
    res.json({ Error: 'This collection are empty.' });
  } else {
    res.json(Model);
  }
});

// Find bots by their names | WORKING
router.get('/:name', async (req, res) => {
  const botName = req.params.name;

  try {
    const Model = await Bot.findOne({ name: botName });
    res.json(Model);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ Error: 'This bot does not exists.' });
  }
});

// Find bots by their ownerId | NOT WORKING
router.get('/:ownerId', (req, res) => {
  const ownerId = req.params.ownerId;

  res.json({ ownerId: ownerId });
});
```

Comment: van you show all GET routes related to `/bots`?

Comment: I have updated the question, check there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes `/:name` and `/:ownerId` are the same. If you take URL `http://localhost:3000/bots/123` then you cannot say what is 123 - is it a name of a bot or an owner id.
The way you defined these routes **all** such requests would be processed by the first handler i.e. by `/:name`.

You should distinguish these two routes somehow. Or you can combine all 3 of them into one route with two optional query params:

```
http://localhost:3000/bots?name=123&ownerId=111 // gets bots with name=123 and with ownerId=111
http://localhost:3000/bots?ownerId=111
http://localhost:3000/bots?name=123
http://localhost:3000/bots // gets all bots without conditions
```

Comment: Ow, thanks, I have not notice that. But, if I use query, i can some how remove the path parameter from the get? Or I have to remove the parameter from the index.js on App.use?

Comment: You can leave only `router.get('/', async (req, res) => {` adding there a support for two query params

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you pass by the /:name route because for express there is no way to distinguish /:ownerId from /:name. As the order is important, you can switch /:name and /:ownerId route declarations in order to check this behaviour.

But for your main problem, may be you can add a string pattern to distinguish /:name and /:ownerId (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)